# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context in new brand empty Xamarin project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Should Xamarin development work out of the box?

I have updated Visual Studio, have updated Android Development and just created new empty Xamarin project from template.

Nevertheless, the code has severe problem having `InitializeComponent()` not defined.

How to fix?

---

The definition is following:

```
namespace App2
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. it is `partial class`. Unfortunately, I can't find another parts of the class.

Comment: this could be an issue with xaml namespace, also if If the class names aren't the same you'll get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a false positive. Your intellisense might be having some problems.

**Listed below** are the things I did whenever I encountered that particular problem.

```
Unload and Reload the projects

Remove Xamarin.Forms and Re-Install Xamarin.forms.

Update all your nugets packages.

Clean and Build solution.

There was a few times when I had to even restart my PC.
```

> If that did not solve the issues. Delete your bins and obj files from
>   the window explorer. Clean your project, Rebuild it, change your XAML
>   file properties (Build Action) from Embedded Resource to Compile,
>   Rebuild your project (will throw errors), switch back your XAML file
>   properties to Embedded Resource, Rebuild. *This should be good.*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem everytime. I first clean the solution, then restart Visual Studio, then I rebuild.

Try that :)